# Two tefillin dispute: Rambam, Rashi and Rabbeinu Tam, what are we missing?

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, rambam, tefilin, rabbeinu-tam

This dispute was back and forth many times.
But I would love to make some clarity and understand (really understand) how Rabbeinu Tam tefillin can be **seriously** accepted by Hasidic community as a sign to be careful to fulfill mistvah during Shakharis?
Same way Rabbeinu Tam could say we need to wash hands in second order and make conflict with Halakha and now we need to wash hands JUST IN CASE in 2 orders or mezuzah needs to be placed horizontal(?!) and now JUST IN CASE I have to put 2 mezuzas or placing 1 diagonal?

Please lets read carefully what Gemara says about order of tefillin:
Menachot 34B

> ת"ר כיצד סדרן קדש לי והי' כי יביאך מימין שמע והי' אם שמוע משמאל

Jews always count from right!, how it can be placed
3,4,2,1?

Also brilliant comment of Rambam where in entire Mishneh Torah, Tefillin, Mezuzah
Everything is written in such a details about ink, requirements and etc.

Mishneh Torah, Tefillin, Mezuzah and the Torah Scroll 3:5

> כֵּיצַד סִדּוּר הַפָּרָשִׁיּוֹת בִּתְפִלָּה שֶׁל רֹאשׁ. מַכְנִיס
> פָּרָשָׁה אַחֲרוֹנָה שֶׁהִיא (דברים יא יג) ״וְהָיָה אִם שָׁמֹעַ״
> בְּבַיִת רִאשׁוֹן שֶׁהוּא עַל יְמִין הַמֵּנִיחַ. וּ (דברים ו ד)
> ״שְׁמַע״ סְמוּכָה לָהּ. (שמות יג יא) ״וְהָיָה כִי יְבִיאֲךָ״ בְּבַיִת
> שְׁלִישִׁי סְמוּכָה לִשְׁמַע. וְ(שמות יג ב) ״קַדֶּשׁ לִי״ בְּבַיִת
> רְבִיעִי שֶׁהוּא לִשְׂמֹאל הַמֵּנִיחַ תְּפִלִּין כְּדֵי שֶׁיְּהֵא
> הַקּוֹרֵא שֶׁלְּפָנָיו כְּנֶגֶד פְּנֵי הַמֵּנִיחַ קוֹרֵא עַל הַסֵּדֶר
> הַזֶּה כְּגוֹן זֶה: וְאִם הֶחֱלִיף סִדּוּר זֶה פְּסוּלוֹת:

Everything before and after here Rambam wrote diligently correct and missed order?

I can't understand and it does not go in my mind, how is it possible that we accept Rabbeinu Tam tefillin seriously and Hasidic community JUST in case use second tefillin where Rambam clearly says it is not valid.

What is the strongest argument that you use for yourself as solid argument that we do really need second tefillin? What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: Rabbeinu Tam was a contemporary of the Rambam and entitled to disagree with him. The idea of accounting for both views is not merely a Hasidic custom; it's mentioned in Shulchan Aruch.

Comment: @shmosel yes, but how does it make valid? Entitled to disagree based on what?
The same way some other Rabbi could say it should be 3,4,1,2? It doesn't go against Gemara, cause technically 1,2 are on the right and 3,4 are on the left, so we will need to davn with third tefillin? It just doesn't make any sense

It is mentioned in SA - yes, but is there any proper explanation to it?

Comment: It is important to note that this debate did not originate with R. Tam / Rashi. During the Geonic era, this was also debated and there is archaeological evidence from the Dead Sea Scrolls that both orders were in circulation, which pushes this debate quite a bit further back. Either way, everyone agrees that the normative halakhah as observed is according to the "Rashi" order and those that wear the alternative "R. Tam" do it in addition rather than to the exclusion of that order.

Comment: @Deuteronomy While that is what many people say, to paraphrase Mark Twain: the rumors of ancient evidence for RT have been greatly exaggerated. At best there are a couple ambiguous archaeological finds and some conflicting second hand testimony about certain geonim.

Comment: @DoubleAA Lawrence Schiffman (Encyclopedia of the Dead Sea Scrolls, p. 676) states that RT ordered tefillin were found at Waddi Murabba'ai for whatever that's worth. As for the Geonim, I seem to recall R. Hai, R. Sherira (and possibly the Rasag) being cited to such effect. But as you say, that may be second-hand from Rishonim defending R. Tam which naturally is not as authoritative as something directly from them... I'll have a look when I have a chance. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Deuteronomy Yigael Yadin said it first IINM and he gets quoted in rabbinic circles bc it's cool but if you look at the actual klaf the sections are somewhat overlapping and it's really not clear it was intentionally RT and not a sofer doing his best to squeeze things into limited space without needing the writing to make a rectangle

Comment: @DoubleAA I just came across this well written [essay](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/40753443.pdf) by Yehudah Cohn that seems to be taking your tact and traces it all. Thanks for prompting me to find it.

Comment: I think you need to learn more about how halacha works, before this question is going to make sense. Rabbeinu Tam is trying to read the gemara, same as you, and he explains why he read it that way. - It is worth mentioning that the Rambam himself says (letter to Chachmei Lunil, quoted in the Beis Yosef and Kesef Mishnah) that the custom corresponding to Rabbeinu Tam was the common custom some of the time in the ancient yeshivos in Bavel. At a certain point they changed for reasons he mentions.

Comment: There are many many places in the halacha where we do something as an additional strictness, to follow a "דעת יחיד" opinion (from an individual source) which is not the majority opinion. But that is not really the case here. Several Rishonim agree with Rabbeinu Tam, and the Rosh actually suggests doing like both because he doesn't want to choose one.

Comment: @MichoelR If follow and look what exactly it says in scrolls of tefillin how we can place V'haya im shamoa before Shema? It doesn't make any sense to me. Shema is saying about Hashem is One and we need to put tefillin and mezuza.

Comment: @MichoelR But  V'haya im shamoa completes all scrolls before! It says love your G'd, put tefillin, mezuzah, all commandments, what happens if you have other G'ds, if you not follow commandments what kind of punishments, if you follow what kind of rewards. It completes everything, timeline of Torah is also goes this way by scrolls, they are described in order which makes total sense and Shema is part of it and V'haya im shamoa completes everything and all scrolls before! How it can be placed before Shema?

Comment: @MichoelR second question is if my shel yad is following order, how my shel rush will not? I will not feel comfortable davning this way at all.

Comment: @SarDauMort https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/92588/759

Comment: @DoubleAA yes! but still it doesn't give a right to mix the order. I am undermining Rashi tefillin and order of Torah also. Still I can't see anyhow how it can be valid.

Comment: @SarDauMort Who said anything about mixing the order?

Comment: @DoubleAA "From a Rabbenu-Tam/Raavad perspective, the same argument applies: in the head Tefillin the "correct" perspective for reading is from the outside in, so you put section 1 and 3 in an outer box and then 2 and 4 respectively in the box just inward from it.". It does change order, I can't look outside in or inside out. There is a from right to left. Any other games - may change the order and I end up with Rab Tam tefillin. I have order in shel yad, same as in shel rush. That's it. Outside in, inside out are games with tefillin.

Answer (score 2):

You asked:

> What is the strongest argument that you use for yourself as solid argument that we do really need second tefillin?

I would suggest it's the Shulchan Aruch in [סימן לד](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.34.2?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) that says:

> **ב** יְרֵא שָׁמַיִם יֵצֵא יְדֵי שְׁנֵיהֶם‏

Once Maran Bet Yosef says so, you  know you can rely on it. You can find the source of his Psak in the [Tur (ibid)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tur%2C_Orach_Chaim.34.1?lang=he&with=Bach&lang2=he).

> ובדבר זה נפל מחלוקת בין הגאונים יש מהם סוברים כדברי רש"י ויש מהם כדברי ר"ת וכתב א"א ז"ל לפי שנחלקו בו גאוני עולם ותפילין של אלו פסולין לאלו דתניא החליף פרשיותיה פי' שנתן של בית זה בזה פסולין ואמרו חכמים מקום יש בראש להניח בו שני תפילין וכן בזרוע לכן ירא שמים יצא ידי שניהם    ויעשה ב' זוגות תפילין ויניח שניהם ויכוין בהנחתן באותן שעשויין כתקונן אליבא דהלכתא בהם אני יוצא ידי חובתי והאחרים הרי הן כרצועות בעלמא ואין כאן משום בל תוסיף דלא מיקרי בל תוסיף אלא כשעושה ה' בתים ולא יניח ב' הזוגות בכיס א' שהאחד מהם הוא חול ואסור לתתם בכיס של תפילין אלא יעשה שני כיסין וסימן לכל כיס שלא יתן של זה בזה. וכן היה נוהג א"א ז"ל ורבו רבינו מאיר ז"ל:‏

As the [ב"ח](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tur%2C_Orach_Chaim.34.1?lang=he&with=Bach&lang2=he) explains, it's an argument dating back to the Gaonim already, what the correct explanation of the ברייתא is that you quoted in the Rambam.

Disclosure: I only wear 1 pair of Tefillin, following my ancestors' custom.

Comment: Thank you for you great answer!